# Azure DevOps creating Environment variables for actions in inline bash scripts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-task-groups

[image]I want to pass my environment variable as an Empty string or else with some "xyz" string based on my build requirement.

Is there any way to pass empty string ? [image]

Comment: You mentioned Bash but your screenshot is from the Variable tab. you said "empty or else with some xyz" and in you last line you say only empty. what **exactly** is your question?

Comment: yes its from variable tab, and i can pass any string like "xyz" but how to pass empty string there ? like "", ' ', all this option not consider as empty string

Comment: Did you try instated of write "xyz" just leave it empty?

Comment: if you leave it empty it will disable save button so it means it excepted some value

Comment: I succeeded to leave it empty and save, check again.

Comment: i just added screen capture, please check its mandatory to pass value

Comment: Oh ok, I though you talked about general variables to the build definition, in the variables tab. If you define the variable there it can helps you?